# pyodbc fast_executemany with Access ODBC crashes Python interpreter

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm trying to generate and insert many (>1.000.000) Rows in a MS Access Database. For the generation I use numpy functions, therefore I try to access the database with python. I started with pyodbc:

```
import numpy as np
import pyodbc as db
connection_string = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:/Users.../DataCreation.accdb;"
connection = db.connect(connection_string)
cur = connection.cursor()

k = 0
numberofdatasets=1000

for l in range(50):
    params=np.empty(numberofdatasets, dtype=[('valnr', int),('val', float)])

    for j in range(numberofdatasets):
        params[j]= (k, somevalue generated with a numpy function)      
        k=k+1

    params = np.array(params).tolist()
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO DataFinal VALUES (1,?,1,?);", params)

    connection.commit()

connection.close()
```

This works, but takes way too long for being useful to me. I timed it and the problem is the

```
cur.executemany
```

I searched the internet and found the fast_executemany flag. But when I add the line

```
cur.fast_executemany = True
```

my kernel dies. Does anyone have an idea why? I'm using 64bit Windows 10, Python 3.6, Spyder 3.2.8 and MS Access 2016. Please don't suggest not using MS Access, I'm aware there are more efficient databases to do this, but right now this is all I can use. I also am aware that it might not be best du first generate the numpy array and then turn it into a list. My next try was turbodbc and its function

```
 cursor.executemanycolumns
```

but this threw an error from the driver and therefore is a different problem I believe. Any help is appreciated but maybe I should add that I just started using Python in connection with databases and I prefer to understand the problem at least a bit and not just copy some mystery code :) Thanks.

Comment: when you say "my kernel dies" do you mean you get a BSOD from Windows?  Or something else?

Comment: *This works, but takes way too long for being useful to me.* ... how long is this? 5 mins? 5 hours? And how often do you need to insert 1 million records? Do note: MS Access has a [2GB size limit](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c). It can indeed cover more then 1 million but if your table is wide with handful of text columns, the bytes add up!

Comment: @user1443098 - Not a BSOD, but an APPCRASH in python.exe. (At least that's what happens for me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pyodbc `fast_executemany` feature uses an ODBC mechanism called "parameter arrays". Not all ODBC drivers support parameter arrays, and apparently the Microsoft Access ODBC driver is one that doesn't. As mentioned in the [pyodbc Wiki](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fast_executemany)

> Note that this feature ... is currently only recommended for applications running on Windows that use Microsoft's ODBC Driver for SQL Server.

Comment: I have Python code that writes out two Access tables. Both use 'executemany', both set fast_executemany=True.  One works, the other crashes the kernel.  Both tables have a mix of long-integer, double and short-text fields.

The one that works is outputting 1000 lines, the one that crashes the Kernel tries to output 16 lines.

So I believe the true answer is deeper (and a bit more mysterious).